# Display the pdf through a link in database

Tags: pdf, jsf, oracle-adf

I am working presently on the adf side and I am stuck with some issues.

1. I have a page where I have to display the pdf files. The pdf files are in another site and the links are present in a column of the database.But when I try to access those links they are downloading rather than displaying. I need to display those pdf files in my inline frame rather than downloading.

   I heard many suggestions like write a bean and put the file in session and get display them in page .But I am not clear.

   So please help me on this.

   [image: I have to display the pdf there rather than downloading]
2. I have a check box at the end and the checkbox should be enabled in my page only when the displayed pdf scrolled to end.

Please help me solving those issues.

Comment: you might do better researching how to display a PDF in a JSP or JSF page, since that is what adf faces actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a link to a PDF there is only so much you can do to make it display in the browser. The most important thing you must do on the server that delivers the PDF is to make sure it is presented with the correct MIME-type and **without** a `content-disposition` header value of `attachment`.

After that, it's up to the browser to either show it in a browser tab or to download the file. I know Chrome will show the PDF in the browser when it's linked to, not sure if it also does that when it's linked in an iframe.

I don't think there's a reliable way to make it work the way you want, simply because it's very browser dependent.